# Pythagorean Triples with Nested Loops

Tags: java, loops, nested, pythagorean

Basically I have to list out all possible Pythagorean Triples within the data base of '110' and figure out if 'A' is odd then 'B' must be even and vice versa with 'A' being even and 'B' and 'C' are odd, AND the greatest common factor of a,b, and c must no greater than 1.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Triples_Cavazos {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      Scanner fileIn = new Scanner(new File("triple.dat"));

     int x1, x2, x3;

     for(x1 = 1; x1 <= 110; x1++) {
        for(x2 = x1; x2 <= 110; x2++) {
            for(x3 = x2; x3 <= 110; x3++) {
            int a = x1, b = x2, c = x3;

                if((Math.pow(a, 2) + Math.pow(b, 2)) == Math.pow(c, 2)) {
                    if(a % 2 == 1 && b % 2 == 0 && c % 2 == 0 || a % 2 = 0 && b % 2 == 1 && c % 2 == 0) {
                    System.out.println(a + " " + b + " " + c);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

"triple.dat" base

```
110
```

I'm getting the triples meeting correct but my code seems to run an error with operand bad types and having to find the GCF of a,b, and c.

Comment: Odd plus Even cannot be Even. In other words, if `a` is odd and `b` is even, then `c` must be odd.

Comment: Do not use `Math.pow()` to compute small integer powers of small(ish) integers.  Simply multiply instead.  Multiplication is faster in such cases, and is not subject to rounding error.

Comment: `a % 2 = 0`.  Don't you use an IDE like Eclipse? They even mark it with red lines to indicate exactly where these little silly errors are.

Comment: the Odd square is Odd and the Even square is even.. and then @Phylogenesis is right

Comment: Also, there are [far better ways of calculating primitive Pythagorean triples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_of_primitive_Pythagorean_triples) than just trial and error.